# MYSQL AUTO_INCREMENT in the event of both user register a account at the same time?

Tags: mysql

i am just wondering what happen if both user register a account at the same time.
will AUTO_INCREMENT id number be the same or different?

Comment: **massively** improbable, one will always be before the other.

Comment: It would be different.

Comment: @daniel IF* same time meaning to the very precise exact/moment/milisecond or whatever

Comment: You mean if the two hit at the same time as if by some precision only found in CERN? I think you're over thinking whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Not only is it massively improbable that you can get two such actions done at the same time, it's scientifically impossible to get two of the same auto_increments due to the way it's calculated internally. Bottom line is that you **definitely** don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

**auto-increment locking**

The convenience of an auto-increment primary key involves some tradeoff with **concurrency**. In the simplest case, if one transaction is inserting values into the table, any other transactions must wait to do their own inserts into that table, so that rows inserted by the first transaction receive consecutive primary key values. InnoDB includes optimizations, and the **innodb_autoinc_lock_mode** option, so that you can choose how to trade off between predictable sequences of auto-increment values and maximum concurrency for insert operations.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_auto_increment_locking

http://mysqlinsights.blogspot.in/2009/03/auto-increment-stability.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's through a website, then there is only likely to be one connection at a time (ok there is such a thing such as load balancing etc, but lets not get complicated here) , and theoretically it doesn't happen.

Assuming multiple connections, then what happens depends on which storage engine you use for the database. MyISAM implements table locks whilst InnoDB implements row locks. Both should ensure that you only get one id at a time.

Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the auto-increment functionality guarantees a unique number for each row in the table. The way MySQL is set up, it uses an interlock to serialize these incrementing operations: that is, to complete one before beginning the other. So even if they're somehow presented to the server in the same moment, the numbers will be different.

There's a small downside to this technique. It's possible (extremely unlikely, but possible) that the order of auto-incremented serial numbers will not be what you expect it to be if you try to insert multiple rows almost at once. The server has to choose one to go first, and from the point of view of the application programmer the server chooses arbitrarily. That is, it's permitted to choose in a way that's formally unpredictable.